# Getting CamelExecutionException

Tags: apache-camel

I'm getting the below error in my production environment

DEBUG org.apache.camel.processor.DefaultErrorHandler - Failed delivery for exchangeId: ID-*****-56874-1372457272212-0-1. On delivery attempt: 0 caught: org.apache.camel.CamelExecutionException: Exception occurred during execution on the exchange: Exchange
DEBUG org.apache.camel.processor.Pipeline - Message exchange has failed: so breaking out of pipeline for exchange: Exchange[*******] Handled by the error handler.

Same build with same dependecies is working in 3 of my other environments in LINUX Box. We are using camel-core-2.8.0-fuse and Java 1.6

Comment: This can't possibly be the only error you get. What are you trying to do? Does it always fail, if not - when? Please make some effort trying to pinpoint the error, then submit a question with info enough to understand your case.

Comment: Yes, it is always failing.I tried adding trace="true" in CamelContext and I'm not getting any addition logs or error. I'm kind of stuck with this issue for last 2 days.We are kind of sure that this might be memory issue but I'm not getting any Memeory or Heap Error in Log. I'm reading an incoming file and processing it and populating it in Domain Object(Bean) in Processor, where I'm getting this error.

Answer (score 0):

There were 2 JAR for beans and it was pointing to wrong JAR. After removing the old JAR, error is rectified. Not sure why CAMEL was giving Camel Execution Exception for JAR Issues :(